# Are there any compatible Alternatives to AWS Firehose for local offline Development

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-kinesis-firehose

We are currently using [Minio](https://github.com/minio/minio) as our solution to S3 for local development and we are looking for a similar Solution for AWS FireHose. Has anyone dealt with this, I can't seem to find any existing solutions for this online? It doesn't need to be extremely fast or handle a lot of data but does need to fit in with AWS clients as much as possible

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [localstack](https://github.com/localstack/localstack), which is a local AWS cloud stack. It provides implementations of several of AWS services, including AWS Firehose and also S3.